# SQL query to know skipped number

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi im new to SQL query i only know simple query.
My question is it possible to `SELECT skipped check number EX2001,EX2002,EX2004`
`select result will show EX2003`.
thanks in advance, sorry for my english.
you can answer algorithm only, ill try to implement it to SQL.
example:
SELECT * FROM SETTLEMENT WHERE checkno not in (between ex2001 and ex2900)
is it possible like this? im using MS SQL 2008.

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table sequence(st varchar(50))

 insert into sequence values('EX2001');
 insert into sequence values('EX2002');
 insert into sequence values('EX2004');
 insert into sequence values('EX2005');
 insert into sequence values('EX2008');
```

Assuming your original table name is **sequence** with only one field, you can modify as per your needs

Try below

```
DECLARE @all TABLE
(
st varchar(20) 

)
declare @start int
declare @end int
declare @str varchar(20)
set @start=2000 //define starting point
set @end=2010 //define end point
while(@start<@end)
    BEGIN
        SET @start=@start+1
        set @str='EX'+cast(@start as varchar(20))
        INSERT INTO @all VALUES (''+@str+'') 
    END

SELECT * from @all 
except
select * from sequence
```

output

```
st
EX2003
EX2006
EX2007
EX2009
EX2010
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need hard coded values in query then it can be done like (as you did not posted any code so here is a simple query). you can use `IN()` or `NOT IN()` in sql

```
select * from table where check_number not in ('EX2001','EX2002','EX2004' );
```

Comment: ty for fast reply, but my database is large. is it possible to put range using not in?

Comment: yes it is but as from question it is not clear please post some  code how you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL engine is not mentioned, this answer is only for **Oracle 11G**

**Option 1: With hierarchical queries**

[See Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71415/1/0)

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1 ( A VARCHAR2 ( 9 ) );

INSERT INTO
      TEST1
VALUES
      ( 'EX2001' );

INSERT INTO
      TEST1
VALUES
      ( 'EX2002' );

INSERT INTO
      TEST1
VALUES
      ( 'EX2004' );

COMMIT;

WITH TEST2
    AS (SELECT
             TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR ( A,
                    3 ))
                 AS A
        FROM
             TEST1)
SELECT
        MIN_A
      - 1
      + LEVEL
FROM
      (SELECT
            MIN ( A ) MIN_A,
            MAX ( A ) MAX_A
       FROM
            TEST2)
CONNECT BY
      LEVEL <=   MAX_A
             - MIN_A
             + 1
MINUS
SELECT A FROM TEST2;
```

**Option 2: With Oracle analytics function**

[See Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71415/4/0)

```
WITH T
    AS (SELECT
             TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR ( A,
                    3 ))
                 AS SNO,
                 SYSDATE AS SDATE
        FROM
             TEST1)
SELECT
      SDATE,
      SNO
      + 1
          FIRST_MISSING,
      DECODE ( NEXT_SNO
             - 1,
             SNO
             + 1, TO_NUMBER ( NULL ),
             NEXT_SNO
             - 1 )
          LAST_MISSING
FROM
      (SELECT
            SDATE,
            SNO,
            LAG ( SNO )
                OVER ( PARTITION BY  SDATE 
                      ORDER BY SNO )
                LAST_SNO,
            LEAD ( SNO )
                OVER ( PARTITION BY SDATE
                      ORDER BY SNO )
                NEXT_SNO
       FROM
            T)
WHERE
      NVL ( NEXT_SNO,
           SNO
           + 1 ) <> SNO
                  + 1;
```

Comment: ty for reply, will using hierarchi process